# How to pick(picker view) any files from ios device using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was developing an ios application for file backup. In that I need to list and enable user to pick up files from any folder and need to do email backup like media and image picker.

I am struckup here with a bottle neck. I can't triger populating the list of document and email list for the user to pick. I had tried many codes, but it is not working.

I was working with the simulator.

Could anyone share their insight?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should be more precise : do you want to pick up any file from any application on your device or just in your application library folder ? You can't access others applications folders.
You can find more information about the file system here : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

iPhone do not have a file browser.
The only place that a iPhone app can take file is from photo album.
Every application keeps its files in its private place.